# How to show input of JTextField in JLabel ? how to fix error in reflection ?

Tags: java, swing, reflection, jlabel, jtextfield

i have to do this: i have one JTextField and button. And when i write to that TextField output must show result in JLabel.

1. Asks the user to provide the name of a class.
2. Uses Class.forName() to get an access to Java Reflection API.
3. Creates a new instance (i.e. object) of the class using the default constructor.
4. Finds and displays all fields of the class in the form including inherited fields:

field_type  field_name: (field_value(JTextField))(Set(Button))

field_value must be a textbox, so that the user can change the value by pressing ‘Set’ button.  The new value must be updated to the object.  If the field contains values of complex types (objects, collections etc.) then the textbox and ‘Set’ button should not be created.

1. Finds and displays all methods of the class including inherited methods:
   return_type method_name (param_type1 (param_value1(JTextField)), param_type2(param_value2(JTextField)) , ..) (Invoke(Button))

If a method has parameters of complex types (objects, collections etc.) then only parameters’ types are displayed, param_values’ textboxes and ‘invoke’ button are skipped.
When the user presses “invoke” button, the application must invoke the method. Make sure that if the method alters the fields’ values these changes are displayed.

and my code here:

```
     import java.awt.FlowLayout;
     import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
     import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
     import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
     import java.lang.reflect.Field;
     import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
     import java.lang.reflect.Method;
     import java.lang.StringBuffer;
     import java.util.Scanner;
     import javax.swing.JButton;
     import javax.swing.JFrame;
     import javax.swing.JLabel;
     import javax.swing.JPanel;
     import javax.swing.JTextField;

     public class ReflectionTest {

private String class_name = "java.lang.StringBuffer";

public ReflectionTest() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException{
    JLabel jl1 = null, jl2, jl3, jl4;
    JFrame jf = new JFrame("New");
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
     JTextField jtf = new JTextField(20);
     JButton jb = new JButton("Press");
     jtf.setVisible(true);
     jp.add(jb);
     jp.add(jtf);

     jf.add(jp);
     jf.setVisible(true);
     jf.setSize(400, 550);
     jf.setResizable(false);


     String text = jtf.getText().toString();

     Class cs = Class.forName(text);

     jb.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                         // THIS CODE IS EXECUTED WHEN RETURN IS TYPED
                    }
                }
            );

    for(Constructor c: cs.getConstructors()){
        for(Class p: c.getParameterTypes())
            System.out.print(p.getName()+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }

    Constructor c = cs.getConstructor(new Class[]{String.class});
    Object list = c.newInstance("AA");


    Field pub_fields[] = cs.getFields();
    Field all_fields[] = cs.getDeclaredFields();
    System.out.println("Public fields:");
    for(Field f:pub_fields){

        //Showing public fields
        System.out.println();
        jl1 = new JLabel(f.getType().getName() + " " + f.getName());
        jp.add(jl1);
        jl1.setVisible(true);
                }
    System.out.println("All declared fields:");
    for(Field f:all_fields){

        //Showing all declared fields

        jl2 = new JLabel(f.getType().getName() + " "+f.getName()+" ");
        jp.add(jl2);
        jl2.setVisible(true);

        f.setAccessible(true);
        Object val = f.get(list);
        if (val != null){
            //System.out.println(val.toString());
            jl3 = new JLabel(val.toString());
            jp.add(jl3);
            jl3.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println();
            }
        else{
            System.out.println("NULL");
        //f.get(list1);
    }
    }

}

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new ReflectionTest();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  }
```

and i have error. Eclipse show it in this line:
Class cs = Class.forName(text);

Comment: What error is eclipse showing?

Comment: tag edit: [tag:java-ee] tag removed as question has nothing to do with Java Enterprise Edition. [tag:swing] tag added as it has all to do with Swing.

Comment: Please see edit to answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you test the text String before the exception occurs, for instance by printing it out:

```
  System.out.printf("text = \"%s\"%n", text);
  Class cs = Class.forName(text);
```

Which returns:

```
text = ""
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at pkg.ReflectionTest.<init>(ReflectionTest.java:42)
    at pkg.ReflectionTest.main(ReflectionTest.java:102)
```

You'll see that the text String is empty, `""`. This is because you have no text when you call the `Class cs = Class.forName(text);` since it's being called before the GUI has been rendered, much less give the user time to enter text. Only call this in code that is called due to a user-generated event of some sort such as an ActionListener's actionPerformed method.

In other words, add the critical code to where ***in your own commment*** you state you should add the code:

```
  jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // THIS CODE IS EXECUTED WHEN RETURN IS TYPED  // *********!!!!
     }
  });
```

And I second the comment that you should show any and all information about the exception. Please don't make us guess what the problem is.

**Edit**
Also you will have a problem with using local variables, including the JLabels and JTextField, inside of the anonymous inner listener class. The easiest and best way to solve this is to make the variables that need to be accessed in this listener private class fields. So remove their declarations from the constructor and instead move them to the class itself.

Comment: +1 for Edit, this is job for DocumentListener, not shoting with fragile & hacky Reflection,

Comment: @mKorbel: I think that he might need Reflection regardless, as that appears to be the crux of the assignment -- to show in the GUI the components of an object of any class, and to allow modification of them through the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Is it really an error or a "yellow" line? `Class` is a parametized type and if you do not use generics then eclipse will show a warning.

To eliminate such a warning, simply do a

```
Class<?> cs = Class.forName(text);
```

The wildcard is ok because you really don't know which "type" of Class you're going to load.

Comment: (upvoter - I completely changed the content of my answer, the first one was plain wrong. just FYI)

Comment: I overlooked that the constructor throws the exception so a missing exception handling couldn't have been the problem.